# Selecting and filtering latest element in array

Tags: json, sorting, jq, chronological

I have the following sample data:

```
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "Name": "CoreOS-alpha-1939.0.0-hvm",
            "CreationDate": "2014-12-24T23:00:48.000Z"
        },
        {
            "Name": "CoreOS-stable-522.3.0",
            "CreationDate": "2014-12-24T23:00:48.000Z"
        },
        {
            "Name": "CoreOS-stable-600.3.0",
            "CreationDate": "2019-12-24T23:00:48.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the `Name` of the most recent (by `CreationDate`) image that contains "stable" in its `Name`.

My naive attempt is:

```
jq '.Images[] | select(.Name | contains("stable")) |= sort_by(.CreationDate)' data.json
```

However this is giving me an error, and would only sort them by `CreationDate` (not only return the latest one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '.Images | map(select(.Name | index("stable"))) | max_by(.CreationDate).Name' file
CoreOS-stable-600.3.0
```

since `contains` is a bit overkill for checking a string for its containment in another string, `index` is used instead.
`max_by` is used because it avoids sorting and yields the element with max. `CreationDate`.